# How to add data attribute in Rails form select tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-select

I found this [Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) project and its [gem for Rails](https://github.com/Slashek/bootstrap-select-rails). I want to implement search in the select tag.

I do inspect element and here is the HTML source:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

How do I add `data-live-search="true"` inside my form select tag?

My form select:

```
<%= f.select :food_id, options_for_select(Food.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, f.object.food_id), {}, {class: "form-control selectpicker"} %>
```

What I've tried:

```
<%= f.select :food_id, options_for_select(Food.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, f.object.food_id), {}, {class: "form-control selectpicker", data: "live-search"} %>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried `{class: "form-control selectpicker", "data-live-search" => "true" }`?

Comment: Or, `data: { 'live-search' => 'true' }`.

Comment: `{class: "form-control selectpicker", "data-live-search" => "true"}` working. But the search part is not working now. Weird.

Comment: What is _search part_?

Comment: Now I have this: `<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="order[foods_orders_attributes][0][food_id]" id="order_foods_orders_attributes_0_food_id"><option selected="selected" value="7">Nasi Ayam</option>
<option value="9">Kebab</option></select>` But it's not working.

Comment: What is exactly not working?

Comment: I have this helper: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f0d0666b9ef543ec1ffa. The search functionality only works on saved record. But when I try to add a new record, it's not working. See this - http://i.imgur.com/h6NAE9O.gif // Both saved & new `select` tag have the `data-live-search="true"`.

Comment: i assume you should `reinitialize` your js, because it's new element and `selectpicker` not initialized for it.

Comment: try it out in browser console after append first input as like in your screen http://i.imgur.com/h6NAE9O.gif, run in browser console `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` and check again, let me know if it works.

Comment: It works. Ok, what should I do now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86912/discussion-between--and-zulhfreelancer).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try:

```
{class: "form-control selectpicker", "data-live-search" => "true" }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After one day searching, it solves my problem! ;)

Answer (score 25):

```
<%= f.select :food_id, options_for_select(Food.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, f.object.food_id), {}, {class: "form-control selectpicker", data: {"live-search": true}} %>
```

Comment: I vote up, because it is full answer with correct example, not just some partial code

Answer (score 4):

```
  <%= f.select(:plan_id, {},{}, {'v-model'=>"plan_id",'@change'=>"onChange", class: "form-control"}) do  %>
<% Plan.all.each do |plan| %>
    <%= content_tag(:option,"#{plan.name.upcase} #{plan.max_items}  #{number_to_currency(plan.price)}", value:plan.id, :data => {items: plan.max_items, price: plan.price}) %>
<% end%>
<% end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are passing a block to the select, you need to pass `{}` two times, e.g.

```
    => f.select :to_user_id, {}, {}, data: { placeholder: "Choisis des invités..." }, class: "chosen-image" do
      - User.find_each do |user|
        option(data-img-src="#{user_image_url_for(user)}" value="#{user.id}")
          = user.first_name
```