# Rails Select Helper for Forms with Data and HTML attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a Select element using Rails `form_for` helper. This is what I'm trying to create:

```
<label for="charge_occurrence">When to charge</label>
<select class="w-select" data-name="charge_occurrence" id="charge_occurrence" name="charge_occurrence" required="required">
  <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="episodic">Per episode</option>
</select>
```

I have tried several variations of this:

```
<%= f.select :charge_occurrence, [['Monthly', 'monthly'], ['Per Episode', 'episodic']], data: {name: 'charge_occurrence'}, html: {class: "w-input", maxlength: "256", required: "required"} %>
```

I can get everything to work except for the `data-name` part.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<%= f.select :charge_occurrence, [['Monthly', 'monthly'], ['Per Episode', 'episodic']], html: {'data-name' => 'charge_occurence', class: "w-input", maxlength: "256", required: "required"} %>`

See: [How to add data attribute in Rails form select tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993695/how-to-add-data-attribute-in-rails-form-select-tag)

Comment: Thanks xarthnax, that helped. Now I have this: `<%= f.select :charge_occurrence, [['Monthly', 'monthly'], ['Per Episode', 'episodic']], {include_blank: false}, {'data-name': 'charge_occurrence', class: "w-input", maxlength: "256", required: "required"} %>` and the attributes are all correct but it's still showing a blank value that I don't want